# The route.rb doesn't point to my custom RegistrationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, doorkeeper

i build a ruby on rails app base on dookeeper and devise and now I'm going to change the default RegistrationController that is in Devise::RegistrationsController which made by default on ruby to the custom one that i made in a folder api/users/registrationController.
i tried several ways one of is this:

```
devise_for :users,
      only: :registrations,
      controllers: {
        registrations: 'api/users/RegistrationsController'
      }
```

but i get error that says this:

```
'api/RegistrationsController' is not a supported controller name. This can lead to potential routing problems. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use
```

the ways that i declare the RegistrationController is like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    respond_to :json
end
```

of course i made some method in like create in this file file but when i send post request like localhost:3000/users and a json file it refer me to this class class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController and check whole process here.

Comment: `api/users/registrations`

Comment: @Iceman i add this like as RichardAE said in below answer but it doesn't work any more and i also change the path to localhost:3000/api/users and tried to get result and get this error from postman

Comment: LoadError in Api::Users::RegistrationsController#create
Unable to autoload constant Api::Users::RegistrationsController, expected /home/****/ rails hell/****/app/controllers/api/users/registrations_controller.rb to define it

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have the word 'Controller' in the string, and you need to downcase it too:

```
'api/users/registrations'
```

Comment: still get this {"errors":{"email":["can't be blank"]}}